# How can I use the biopython Restriction package with all enzymes that are on REBASE?

Tags: biopython

I want to search a sequence for the enzyme CneH16IP, which has the recognition site GAYNNNNNCTTGY. When I import the list of enzymes included in the Restriction package, the enzyme is not included (code below)

```
from Bio import Restriction
from Bio.Restriction import *
dir()
```

I am assuming that not all of the enzymes from REBASE are imported by default, so is there a way to import all of them as an option? Or to add new enzymes? Alternatively, should I just try to do a string search that allows the degenerate bases and discontinuous bases?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try posting here : https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ too

Comment: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html#6.1

Comment: I'll try updating the library! It seems like the issue is that the set of enzymes pulled is a pared down set, not that the enzyme was added recently.